# Function for finding and returning the match from a regular expression

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for a function which will try to find and return whatever was matched by the regular expression `\\(\\S-\\)` and probably nil if nothing was found.  The search should start from `(point)` and search to the end of the document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `re-search-forward` and `match-string`:

```
(when (re-search-forward "\\(\\S-\\)" nil t)
  (match-string 1))
```

If you don't want point to move, wrap it in a `save-excursion`:

```
(save-excursion
  (when ...
```